# efficient python raw_input and serial port polling

Tags: python, multithreading, serial-port, polling, raw-input

I am working on a python project that is polling for data on a COM port and also polling for user input. As of now, the program is working flawlessly but seems to be inefficient. I have the serial port polling occurring in a while loop running in a separate thread and sticking data into a Queue. The user input polling is also occurring in a while loop running in a separate thread sticking input into a Queue. Unfortunately I have too much code and posting it would take away from the point of the question.

So is there a more efficient way to poll a serial or raw_input() without sticking them in an infinite loop and running them in their own thread?

I have been doing a lot of research on this topic and keep coming across the "separate thread and Queue" paradigm. However, when I run this program I am using nearly 30% of my CPU resources on a quad-core i7. There has to be a better way.

I have worked with ISR's in C and was hoping there is something similar to interrupts that I could be using. My recent research has uncovered a lot of "Event" libraries with callbacks but I can't seems to wrap my head around how they would fit in my situation. I am developing on a Windows 7 (64-bit) machine but will be moving the finished product to a RPi when I am finished. I'm not looking for code, I just need to be pointed in the right direction. Thank you for any info.

Comment: When you saw the 30% CPU resources being used, was there data actively coming over the COM port? Two loops that wait for input shouldn't be using any CPU when idle, since they're both I/O operations.

Comment: @dano I am seeing data come over the COM port every couple of seconds so it should be insignificant. Maybe my CPU usage is coming from the infinite loop that is continuously checking for data in the two Queues?

Comment: Yes, if you're continuously polling both queues in the one thread using `get_nowait` or some other non-blocking `get` call, that's probably what's using the CPU cycles. Could you refactor the code so that one queue is shared with all three threads? You could change the payload of the messages you put into the queue so that you can identify which thread it's from (COM or raw_input), and then just use a blocking `queue.get` in the main thread.

Comment: @dano You're right, I am using `get_nowait` in my main thread for polling both queues. I can easily refactor things so they share a queue and I will give the payloads an identifier as you have suggested. So by using the blocking version (`get`) the queue will not be polled until one of my separate threads has added something to it? Or I am completely missing the idea of blocking vs. non-blocking when polling a queue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're seeing the high CPU usage because your main thread is using the non-blocking `get_nowait` call to poll two different queues in an infinite loop, which means most of the time your loop is going to be constantly looping. Constantly running through the loop uses CPU cycles, just as any tight infinite loop does. To avoid using lots of CPU, you want to have your infinite loops use blocking I/O, so that they wait until there's actually data to process before continuing. This way, you're not constantly running through the loop, and therefore using CPU.

So, user input thread:

```
while True:
    data = raw_input() # This blocks, and won't use CPU while doing so
    queue.put({'type' : 'input' : 'data' : data})
```

COM thread:

```
while True:
    data = com.get_com_data()  # This blocks, and won't use CPU while doing so
    queue.put({'type' : 'COM' : 'data' : data})
```

main thread:

```
while True:
    data = queue.get() # This call will block, and won't use CPU while doing so
    # process data
```

The blocking `get` call will just wait until it's woken up by a `put` in another thread, using a `threading.Condition` object. It's not repeatedly polling. From `Queue.py`:

```
# Notify not_empty whenever an item is added to the queue; a
# thread waiting to get is notified then.
self.not_empty = _threading.Condition(self.mutex)
```

...

```
def get(self, block=True, timeout=None):
    self.not_empty.acquire()
    try:
        if not block:
            if not self._qsize():
                raise Empty
        elif timeout is None:
            while not self._qsize():
                self.not_empty.wait()  # This is where the code blocks
        elif timeout < 0:
            raise ValueError("'timeout' must be a non-negative number")
        else:
            endtime = _time() + timeout
            while not self._qsize():
                remaining = endtime - _time()
                if remaining <= 0.0:
                    raise Empty
                self.not_empty.wait(remaining)
        item = self._get()
        self.not_full.notify()
        return item
    finally:
        self.not_empty.release()

def put(self, item, block=True, timeout=None):
    self.not_full.acquire()
    try:
        if self.maxsize > 0:
            if not block:
                if self._qsize() == self.maxsize:
                    raise Full
            elif timeout is None:
                while self._qsize() == self.maxsize:
                    self.not_full.wait()
            elif timeout < 0:
                raise ValueError("'timeout' must be a non-negative number")
            else:
                endtime = _time() + timeout
                while self._qsize() == self.maxsize:
                    remaining = endtime - _time()
                    if remaining <= 0.0:
                        raise Full
                    self.not_full.wait(remaining)
        self._put(item)
        self.unfinished_tasks += 1
        self.not_empty.notify()  # This is what wakes up `get`
    finally:
        self.not_full.release()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This was exactly my problem. I'm not used to some of the abstractions of python (though I'm starting to love it) and had no idea that my raw_input and com polling loops were blocking calls. That makes much more sense and saved me days worth of fighting with it I'm sure. Thanks again!

Comment: @andNoob Yep, that way both the background threads can feed input into the main thread.